# ¿Es posible enviar a imprimir solo con el nombre de la impresora local por CMD?

Tags: windows, cmd, batch

Intento enviar a imprimir desde linea de comandos especificando solo con el nombre de la impresora:

```
C:\> print file.txt /D:epson
```

Pero al intentar esto me sale el siguiente mensaje:

> No se puede incializar el dispositivo epson

Requiero que pueda imprimirse **solo especificando el  nombre de la impresora** , o que detecte la impresora por dafault.

¿Es posible?

Answer (score 0):

Para una lista de imprimadores, en Win10

```
wmic printer list brief
```

En mi caso, la imprimadora está en la red.  Entonces, dije

```
print hello.txt  /d:\\SERVIDOR.dominio.com.ar\P446S07759
```